# Which preprocessor symbol to check to detect FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, c-preprocessor

I want to compile some piece of c code if I'm on FreeBSD. What `#ifdef` do I use for this?

I realize this is a basic question which the correct web search should answer, but I cannot find the correct search term(s). I've seen code checking `FREEBSD` and/or `__FreeBSD__` and/or `__FreeBSD` but nothing I found mentioned "this is what you need to do".

Answer (score 4):

__FreeBSD__ is the correct one.  I just checked all 3 of those using `gcc -E -`.